# Create list of a list from XML dataset in ElementTree python

Tags: python, xml, list, elementtree

i have a question. How can i create list of a list from xml dataset in ElemenTree python? for example i have this dataset :

```
<data>
    <article>
        <author> Tony </author>
    </article>
    <article>
        <author> Andy </author>
        <author> John </author>
    </article>
    <article>
        <author> Paul </author>
        <author> leon </author>
    </article>
</data>
```

There is a specific function like :

```
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for author in root.iter('author'):
  print(author.text, author.attrib['pid'])
```

that would find and show all author in dataset in single list `[Tony, Andy, John, Paul, Leon]`.  How can i improve those code above so i can get result author in list of s list `[[Tony], [Andy, John], [Paul, Leon]]`? Maybe theres is a specific function to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's quite simple. Just create nested loop to iterate `child` from `root` and then `child2` from `child` with specific tag.

```
author_connection = []

for child in root:
    
    conn = []
    author_connection.append(conn)

    for child2 in child.iter('author'):
        conn.append(child2.text)
```

And the output is

```
[[Tony], [Andy, John], [Paul, Leon]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner can do the magic

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<data>
    <article>
        <author> Tony </author>
    </article>
    <article>
        <author> Andy </author>
        <author> John </author>
    </article>
    <article>
        <author> Paul </author>
        <author> leon </author>
    </article>
</data>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
authors = [[aut.text for aut in art.findall('author')] for art in root.findall('./article')]
print(authors)
```

output

```
[[' Tony '], [' Andy ', ' John '], [' Paul ', ' leon ']]
```

Comment: If we use those `[[aut.text for aut in art.findall('author')] for art in root.findall('./article')]` (still confusing to me), which `for` run first?

Comment: the `article` is the external loop and `author` is the internal loop